# Is there anyway to make a script not run in CMD?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have made a python script but I want to run it like on the desktop and not on CMD because the script wouldn't be able to work if it was ran on CMD. I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.1 . I have tried to find answers on the Python Discord but no one knows how to do that. If there's any other way to make it run just comment. IDK if a shell would work and if that would work please comment below how to do that.

Here's my script

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press('r')
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.release('r')
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.type('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Comment: Take a look at pyinstaller

Comment: Could you elaborate on "*the script wouldn't be able to work if it was ran on CMD*"? Cause at 1st glance it makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean, "run it like on the desktop and not on CMD"? Why would it not work if launched from a command prompt? Why would it work if run "like on the desktop"? Can you post your script to help us understand?

Comment: It's keyboard imputs so i wont work in CMD

Comment: What do you mean? You want to run it as a desktop application, with a GUI and everything?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for using pyinstaller.

Pyinstaller converts python scripts to executable files which are not run from cmd. Here's how to do that:

- Open cmd.
- Install pyinstaller using: `pip install pyinstaller`.
- After it is installed use: `pyinstaller --onefile "ScriptFullPath.py"`.
- Once you are done ✅ you will find it in the path where it is created. If you get an error message you need to install [Visual C++ redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).